# Add order detail metadata to the checkout email and the admin order page in Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

We have products that are defined as "Kits".  They are products that have a list of other products that constitute a kit. The data defining the kit is stored in an array as metadata.  I created a hook that displays the metadata on the product page and in the cart.  I need to do something similar for the "completed order email" and the "admin order page" but I can't figure out how to go about doing that. Here is the hook that I created:

```
add_filter( 'bis_show_kit_meta', 'bis_show_kit_meta_contents', 10, 3 );
function bis_show_kit_meta_contents($productID)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $postMeta = get_post_meta($productID,'',true);
    if ((isset($postMeta['bis_kit_id'])) and ($postMeta['bis_kit_id'][0] > 1)) {
        echo 'This is a Kit containing the following items:<br>';
        echo $postMeta['bis_kit_type'][0].'<br>';
        foreach($postMeta as $kititem) {
            foreach ($kititem as $value) {
                $newvalue = unserialize($value);
                if ($newvalue) {
                    $newvalue2 = unserialize($newvalue);
                    if($newvalue2['type']=="kititem"){
                        echo '<li>' .$newvalue2['quantity']. ' -> ' .chr(9). $newvalue2['name']. '</li>';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The current function is hooked to the respective templates in my child theme.

I can't figure out how to apply a similar function to the `customer-completed-email.php` file and I have no idea where to hook in the admin edit order pages.

I found some code in another post which looks similar to what I need to do but I can't figure out what file the modifications for the admin order is in.

The code I found is:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta','woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta',10,3);

function woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta($item_id, $item, $product){
   ...
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce has already a bunch of hooks that you can use instead of adding your own in WooCommerce templates…

The rule for good development is first to use existing hooks. If no hook is convenient or available, then you can override WooCommerce templates via your child theme. Why? Because templates are updated sometimes, and then you will need to update the edited templates, which is not the case for hooks.

For "Customer Completed Order" notification, use `woocommerce_order_item_meta_end` action hook as follows:

```php
// Setting the email_id as a global variable
add_action('woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'set_email_id_as_a_global', 1, 4);
function set_email_id_as_a_global($order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email = null ){
    if ( $email ) {
        $GLOBALS['email_id_str'] = $email->id;
    }
}

// Displaying custom order item metadata in "Customer Completed Order" email notification
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'custom_email_order_item_meta', 10, 2 );
function custom_email_order_item_meta( $item_id, $item ){
    // Getting the email ID global variable
    $refGlobalsVar = $GLOBALS;
    $email_id = isset($refGlobalsVar['email_id_str']) ? $refGlobalsVar['email_id_str'] : null;

    // Only for "Customer Completed Order" email notification
    if ( ! empty($email_id) && 'customer_completed_order' === $email_id ) {
        bis_show_kit_meta_contents( $item->get_product_id() );
    }
}
```

This will allow you to display your custom metadata in "Customer Completed Order" notification only.

Alternatively, you can replace the hook with `woocommerce_order_item_meta_start` that has the same function variable arguments.

Code goes in your child theme's functions.php file or in a plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  That cleared up a lot about hooks that I didn't quite understand.